Kafka Streams for Aggregation Event Processing and Scalability to a Large Number of Tasks
I have the following task: let's assume I'm developing an online store used by a million users. Users make purchases at different times. Each purchase by each user turns into a transaction event. I would like to process these events immediately, and if a user makes at least three more transactions within the next week or, for example, a month (a configurable time period), I want to give the user some kind of gift.
I would like to ask whether it's possible to implement such a task with Kafka and Kafka Streams. For example, when a user makes their first transaction, I want to assign a task to Kafka Streams to track the number of transactions made by this user from that moment over the course of a week. If the number of new transactions made by that user exceeds 3 within that week, Kafka Streams should generate an event for me.
The challenge is that a million users may make purchases at different times, and in the worst case, I'll need to assign Kafka Streams a million such tasks, each with a unique sliding time window (based on the time of their first transaction in the system). Is it possible to implement this in Kafka Streams, and can they scale to handle that many tasks?


track the number of transactions made by this user from that moment over the course of a week

Yes. Use a SessionWindow starting from the first event. Data will be tracked in RocksDB by default.

need to assign Kafka Streams a million such tasks

Kafka Streams tasks cannot be more than the number of partitions in the topic(s) it is consuming. Kafka cannot handle millions of topics / partitions, and you do not need one topic per user... Start with a UUIDv4 for some user-id, then you could have at least 26 partitions for distributing the first/last character (with a custom Partitioner) of that ID. Use 26 * 26 = 676 partitions for bucketing on the first/last two characters, etc.

Thank you for your response. If I understood correctly, I can implement this using a Session Window, and in the worst-case scenario, I could have up to 1 million concurrent Session Windows running on Kafka, each with different start/end dates, which will aggregate data by userId within those ranges?

Potentially, yes, but they would not be running "on Kafka". Don't run your Streams apps on the brokers themselves.

You could also break the data into a 52 week calendar year, rather than weeks starting from each individual user-event.

Thanks. Unfortunately, I need to start each individual window exactly from the moment the request for that window is made. The exact start date depends on an event that occurred in another system, and this date is always unique. The lifespan of each window can also vary and differ from one another. According to my business logic, I cannot break these windows into clear, fixed, uniform windows for all system users. They are strictly individual. That’s why I want to understand if Kafka can handle this.

Gotcha. Feel free to review the video guides - https://youtu.be/7eO1toucB74 or docs https://developer.confluent.io/courses/kafka-streams/windowing/
